# How to extract the indices of specific value from matrix

Tags: matrix

suppose we have a matrix , and we want to extract zero value from the matrix
the code will be some thing like:

```
 A <- matrix( c(4, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0,5,6,8,9,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,12,34,3,4,5,0,4, 3, 1, 25, 4,0,6,0,4,12,2,3,4,5,6,7,12,7,0), nrow=5,ncol=9,byrow = TRUE)


 w<- which(A  == 0 , arr.ind = TRUE)
```

the indices of zero value are :

```
> w
     row col
[1,]   1   2
[2,]   3   2
[3,]   4   5
[4,]   1   6
[5,]   4   7
[6,]   3   8
[7,]   5   9
```

my question is :how to group the result  of indices into two subsets like

```
    1 2 3 6 8
    4 5 7 9
```

What about if the condition ( extract all the values >= 9)
the result should be two groups

```
1 2 3 4 9
5 7
```

Comment: What's the logic behind the grouping you want?

Comment: I want to group the indexes  based on  direct or indirect relation with others.you can note that:  for first group 1 with 2 and 6 ,  3 with 2  and   8  (8 has relation with 3 only and 3 has relation with 2 and 8 ,while 2 has relation with 1 and 3 ,6 has relation with 1 only). 
while   the second group 4, 5 ,7, 9   don't have relation with the first group for example we don't have 5 with 1  or 4 with 7